# Cannot get response of post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my current Javascript code for sending requests every 5 minutes.

```
function sendRequest() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log($.post('../notify/notify.php', { notify: 1 }).done());
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(sendRequest());
}, 5000);
```

---

When I then check the network in the developer tools, the requests are being sent and the responses are being returned as expected. This is my PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

if(isset($_POST['notify']) && $_POST['notfiy'] == "1") {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'Title' => 'Welcome to our Site',
        'Message' => 'You are current recieving notifications.',
        'Location' => 'http://example.com/',
        'State' => true
    ),true);
} else {
        echo json_encode(array(
        'State' => false
    ), true);
}
```

---

However, when I check the console I see that it is a type `Object {readyState: "1"}` and when I then expand it, the expected response in wrapped inside a `responseText` field. However, `console.log()` returns **undefined** when I append `.responseText` to the end of the `$.post().done()`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the response from my PHP file?

---

**Update:**

After reviewing the questions, I learned that I had the wrong `header()` declared. The type should be `/json` not `/javascript`. Moreover, the response was not readable because like stated, I was only logging the *promise* of the request. I needed to add a `function(param)` inside my `done()` function and then use the response inside of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are wrapping asynchronous call within `console.log()`, expecting `.responseText` or `.responseJSON` of [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType), or parameter of callback function of `$.post()` asynchronous call to be logged at `console`.

`console.log()` does not wait on asynchronous call to be made or completed. `console.log()` will log the jQuery promise object returned
`$.post()`

> However, when I check the console I see that it is a type `Object {readyState: "1"}`

not `.responseText` or `.responseJSON` properties of the `jxXHR` object

> Returns: [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR)

[`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/#deferred-done-doneCallbacks-doneCallbacks) accepts a single function or an array of functions, where you can include `console.log()` within the function body to log the result  of the asynchronous operation `$.post()` that is set as first argument at function callback. `.responseText` or `.responseJSON` is accessible as a property of third argument at `.done()`.

```
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  console.log(data, jqxhr.responseJSON)
})
```

You also set `Content-Type` `headers` at `php` to `"application/javascript"`, though you `echo` an `array` from `php`. `headers` should be set to `"application/json"`. `$.post()` accepts a third parameter which is the expected `Content-Type` or `dataType` of response; here, `"json"`.

```
// declare variable `interval` for ability to call `clearInterval(interval)`
var interval; 
function sendRequest() {
    return $.post('../notify/notify.php', { notify: 1 }, "json")
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    })
    // handle error
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown)
    });
}

$().ready(function() {
   sendRequest().then(function() {
     interval = setInterval(sendRequest, 5000);
   })
})
```

Comment: Ok this works perfectly, I have no idea how but thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you set `header` `Content-Type` to `"application/javascript"` at `php`? Should `Content-Type` be set to `"application/json"`?

Answer (score 1):

The `console.log()` call prints `undefined` to the console because your function `sendRequest` returns nothing.

If you want you can use the `done` promise to do something with the data that your request returend:

```
.done(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: This no longer logs anything in the console, even if I put `console.log('test');`

Comment: Are you sure your request was successful?

Comment: Oh okay, you're right. My request was not successful. Is this due to my PHP code? That code He provided actually throws an exception unexpected token, I do have a rewrite in my .htaccess so maybe that is the reason?

Comment: Probably... the `done` function will run on success. if the request failed the `fail` function will get called.

Comment: I added a route in the program and its now working. Thank's a lot! It was because my `.htaccess` redirects all requests to a index file ;P

Comment: @Dekel _"The `console.log()` call returns `undefined` because your function `sendRequest` returns nothing."_ Is this accurate?

Comment: @guest271314, not so much, i'll change the terminology there :) 1 sec

Comment: @guest271314, updated. check this: `console.log((function(){})())`

Comment: That is still not the reason `console.log()` does not log result of `sendRequest()`

Comment: There is no `result` for the `sendRequest()` call. That function returns nothing, so there is not a real *result* there.

Comment: `console.log((function(){})())` is not the same as `console.log($.post('../notify/notify.php', { notify: 1 }).done());` or `console.log(sendRequest());`. You are correct, no value is returned from `sendRequest()` call, though if `return $.post()` was included at `sendRequest`, would result of `$.post()` be logged at `console` at `console.log(sendRequest());` ?

Comment: if `return $.post()` was inside the `sendRequest()` call - you are correct. But this is not the OP code :)

Comment: `console.log(sendRequest());` is the `javascript` at OP.

Comment: I don't see any `return` inside `function sendRequest() { ... }`. Do you?

Comment: No. `console.log(sendRequest());` is the `javascript` at Question. That is, OP expects the result of `$.post()` to be logged at `console` at `console.log(sendRequest());`.  Your Answer states _"The `console.log()` call prints `undefined` to the console because your function `sendRequest` returns nothing."_ Including `return $.post()` would not log result of `$.post()` request at `console`.

Comment: This might be what we **wanted** but this is not the code he **wrote**. The function (according to the OP) returns nothing, so console.log will print `undefined` in the console. Don't you agree with that?

Comment: OP expects result of `$.post()` to be logged at `console`. At approaches at Question OP wraps  `$.post()` or `sendRequest()` call in `console.log()`. Returning a value from `sendRequest()` will not log result of `$.post()` at `console`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you want. You asked ' "The console.log() call returns undefined because your function sendRequest returns nothing." Is this accurate?` The answer here is yes.

Comment: _"The answer here is yes."_ No, the answer is no. Not accurate within the context of what OP expects to be logged to `console`; that is, the result of `$.post()` request.

Comment: You can sure say "if you change your code to XYZ the console.log will work as you wish", but the reason the current code doesn't work is because it **shouldn't**

Comment: _"because your function `sendRequest` returns nothing."_ Is not entirely correct given `javascript` at Question. OP expects result from `$.post()` to be logged at `console`.

Comment: I'm sorry but *given `javascript` at Question* this is 100% correct :)

Comment: It's like "I have the code `console.log('foo')` and I don't understand what it gives me 'foo' in the console. I want to to give me 'bar'". So - yes, you can change the code to `console.log('bar')`, but the **original** code will give you 'foo' - no matter what. Only if you **change** it - the result will change.

Comment: How would result of `$.post()` be logged at `console` if the value was `return`ed from `sendRequest()` using the pattern at Question:  `console.log(sendRequest())`?

Comment: It will not, and the reason exists in my answer. This is why you **must** change the code if you do you want to log the result of the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('../notify/notify.php', { notify: 1 },function(data){console.log(data);})
```